# Can a Workgroup be part of a Domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain, workgroup

Can a Workgroup be part of a Domain?
If someone could answer me I'd be very thankful.

Comment: `Can a Workgroup be part of a Domain?` No, that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Windows networking: No.

By definition, a workgroup has no central authority. A domain is rooted in Active Directory which requires central authority.